# CURL with 'Bearer token' works fine but same API isn't working on POSTMAP

Tags: api, curl, postman

My Below API using terminal works fine

```
curl -v --header "Authorization: Bearer LgiffI2nL4lEiCle" -X POST "https://<my-url>/api/source/loadAccounts/85296"
```

But When I'm trying the same usimng POSTMAN it's not, why ? I'm getting `403 forbidden`

The `token` expiration time is `1 hour` long, so I'm sure token isn't expired.
[image]

Comment: best guess, it's an IP block, and your terminal is using an allowed IP (ssh'ed into something?), and you're running postman from a blacklisted/not-whitelisted IP.

Comment: another possibility is that curl is a whitelisted user-agent, and postman is not a whitelisted user-agent?

Comment: second seems to be a valid option as we block CSRF requests

Comment: that theory is easy to test, you can tell postman to fake the User-Agent header to mimic curl's. use the -v output from curl to check what agent curl is using (eg, on my system it's `User-Agent: curl/7.52.1` )

Comment: Thanks, it helped. But, it needs to have interceptor enabled. In case of standalone POSTMAN how would I set user agent. POSTMAN saying me that the `restricted header` use postman interceptor

Comment: @hanshenrik Could you put your comment as a answer ? basically I need to install Native POSTMAN app instead of having POSTMAN as chrome extension. your trick `User-Agent: curl/7.52.1` helped me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible that postman's user-agent is not white-listed, while curl's user-agent is white-listed. (and going by the comments, this is probably the case)

another possibility could be that it's an IP block, and your terminal/curl is using an allowed IP (ssh'ed into something?), and you're running postman from a not white-listed IP.

**Edit**

Incase your App server blocking X-CSRF request and terminal/curl is enabled, you need to install **Standalone POSTMAN** and use `User-Agent: curl/7.52.1`